# React navigation 5 - Navigating from one stack to another nested stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

There are numerous questions I have read that seem very similar to my issue but I can not figure this out. I am using the latest react-navigation version 5.

I have a bottom tab navigator with each tab a separate stack view. I am trying to navigate from stack (tab) 3 to one screen deep on stack (tab) 1.

I am able to successfully navigate to the correct nested screen in stack 1 via this code `onPress` from stack 3:

```
navigation.navigate('Cars', { // Stack 1
      screen: 'Nissan', // <- Nested Screen in Stack 1
      params: {
        ... // pass my data here
      },
});
```

But the issue I have is if I first navigate from stack 1 (Cars) to the nested screen (Nissan), **AND THEN** try and navigate from stack 3 to stack 1's nested screen with the code above, it works but I see the old screen (Nissan) and not the expected new screen (Honda, e.g)

If I directly go from stack 3 `onPress` it works correctly and I see the new screen with correct passed data (Honda)

I have tried `.reset` but I must not be using it correctly 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset

Comment: If you navigate to `screen: 'Nissan'` why new screen Honda is expected?
Can you show your stacks?

Comment: Sorry, the car descriptions might just have made it more confusing lol. I want to navigate to the 'Car type' screen which can either be Honda or Nissan, etc based on the params I pass.